# Approximate an infinite sum within some epsilon

Tags: python

I have very little experience in coding and I'm learning Python for a class. I'm being asked to approximate an infinite sum within some desired epsilon such that the difference between two consecutive terms in the series is less than epsilon.

I searched around a little and found out about `'while'` which from my understanding can be used to create an infinite loop. I tried to get an understanding of how it worked and wrote the following:

```
def S(eps):
    z = 1
    S = 0
    while z == 1:
        S = S + (?)
        if S[i] - S[i-1] < eps:
            z = 2
     return z
```

Assuming that'll work to break the loop, the part I'm getting stuck on is trying to define the loop that'll do the actual summation. Whenever I've made a finite loop, I usually do something along the lines of:

```
for i in range(n):
    S = S + whatever[i]
```

where n would be some finite value I've defined somehow. In my problem I don't know what `n` will correspond to the epsilon I need, so I can't assign an n. I don't know any other way to make a loop though.

Could someone please shed some light on what I can do here?

If it matters, the sum I'm trying to do is `(1/k)^3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an unending while loop, use `while True` (which runs for forever) and break out when some conditions are met.

In the example below, I've defined epsilon as 10^-10:

```
sigma, epsilon, k = 0, 10**-10, 1
while True:
    addition = 1.0/(k**3)
    if addition < epsilon:
        break
    else:
        sigma += addition
    k += 1
```

So that the results are:

```
>>> print sigma, k
1.20205679544 2155
```

Note that floating point operations are not reliable for high precision (both `1.0/(k**3)` and `sigma += addition` involve float) and in case you are looking for a lot more precision, (say till 20th position after decimal and so on), use [`decimals`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module.

Comment: Thank you! Took me a little while to understand what was going on and write it as a function but I see how to do it now. I will look into the decimals module.